# On what halachic grounds can you be compensated for teaching Torah?

Tags: torah-study, emes-truth-honesty, chinuch-education

The Tanach says:

Buy truth, but do not sell it. [[Proverbs 23:23]](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.23.23)

Does that mean that a paid Torah teacher is a sinner?  Am I abetting sin by hiring him?

Comment: it comes from "מה אני בחנם - אף אתה בחנם" Nedorim 37

Comment: See the Shiur here : https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=30886